# MD5 checksum of CSV file column rows in terminal

Tags: bash

I'm on OS X.

I have a large list of records and I need to md5 (or any other hash function) nth column and add it to a new column.

There was something that almost worked except that it did not:

> awk '{
>       tmp="echo " $3 " | openssl md5 | cut -f1 -d\" \"" tmp | getline cksum $2=","cksum print }'< file.csv

Thanks for help.

**EDIT**:

My CSV:

> fname,lname,email,cpid,mcssid
>
> tester,testurion,test@test.org,Campaign2014,12345
>   tester,testuci,test@test.com,Campaign2014,123456

Results:

```
dzh:Desktop dzh$ awk '{
    tmp="echo "$0" | openssl md5 | cut -f5 -d\" \""
tmp | getline cksum
$2=","cksum
print
}'< testfile.csv
fname,lname,email,cpid,mcssid ,60a0c14d2af1ac9b429d5323092d46e4
tester,testurion,test@test.org,Campaign2014,12345 ,01ef8935ad33c1a419d5a935f2eced69
tester,testuci,test@test.com,Campaign2014,123456 ,536f1e8583e3e2e1666cf9cda92664db
dzh:Desktop dzh$ md5 -s test@test.com
MD5 ("test@test.com") = b642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4452
dzh:Desktop dzh$ md5 -s testuci
MD5 ("testuci") = c9e9ffe7eb5c77a59b77e897ff56b33c
dzh:Desktop dzh$ md5 -s Campaign2014
MD5 ("Campaign2014") = e9d6e2c2752c3d228783e0fa8134c545
dzh:Desktop dzh$ md5 -s 123456
MD5 ("123456") = e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
```

Comment: What about that didn't work exactly? You need to take care to close piped commands or they stay open (and get re-used for later input).

Comment: Can you show a sample of your input and explain how you would like the output to appear?

Comment: Not sure what $ parameter should be, but played a bit and it does not calculate correct hashes.

Comment: Added sample and results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that seems to work:

```
awk -F "," '{
cmd="md5 -q -s "$3
cmd|getline cksum
close(cmd)
printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, cksum
}' < testfile.csv
```

You need to close the pipe, and I'm using md5 in quiet mode rather than openssl to get the sum. Also, you need -F "," to tell awk that the fields are separated by commas.